# How to detect the use of multiple delimiters in a CSV file?

Tags: python

To my understanding the Python's csv library can infer the used delimiter in a CSV file dynamically or from a list of possibilities. This can be done by looking at the delimiter attribute of the dialect returned by e.g. `csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(1024))`.

Also different delimiters can be given to the .sniff() so that it can check whether or not any of them are used. But how can I check that one and only one (possibly unknown) delimiter is used in the CSV file? This seems like an easy tasks but I haven't found an answer either from the documentation or from Google.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you expect a person much less a function, to determine that a single unknown delimiter is being used?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked.
To me it seems something like: Assuming that decimal separator is period (.), multiple different separators are used if any other symbol than the one right after the first value is encountered.

Comment: How do you recognize "first value"? If you have commas for separators, you can't have negative signs, colons, etc.?  This is an *incredibly* under-determined problem, and as such there's probably a good reason you didn't find anything about how to do such a check.